# Wine tasting like soot

Tags: food-chemistry, taste

I'm not sure if this question is for chemistry.

I had a bottle of (cheap) wine. It had a strong taste of soot, to an extend that I suspected that in the filling process some machine oil might have gotten into it.

I discarded the bottle, but some time later, I've found the same taste, to a lesser extend, in some other wine. Now it looks like my taste buds have become more sensitive to that, as I can taste it now (depending on what, I don't know) quite frequently, mostly on a low scale.

Any idea to explain that?

Comment: Guess you should buy better wine now ;)

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Mithoron define "better wine" as opposed to "wine sold for a higher price" ;-) My "problem" is that some wines sometimes taste like soot, but a month later another bottle from the same market, same brand, same year, same purchase, does not. Looks the difference is in my taste buds.

Comment: @bon thanks for the link, maybe if there will be no satisfying answers her I will have a look there. But I don't like to get hyperactive about this.

Comment: @bon *searching* there is  a good idea which I can do without creating yet another account !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odour and aroma of wine consists of about 600–800 components. Many of these compounds have been described with a range of odour/flavour sensations, even in more than one category, and often have differing flavour impressions, dependent upon their concentrations in aqueous solution or in the air-space above.

The odours and flavours in wine tasting are typically divided into groups, for example: *Floral, Woody, Rustic/Vegetal, Balsamic, Fruity, Animal, Empyreumatic, Chemical, Spicy,* and *Etherish.* [Bakker, J.; Clarke, R. J. *Wine flavour chemistry;* 2nd ed.; Wiley-Blackwell 2012]

What you describe as “strong taste of soot” probably belongs to the *Chemical* group, which is associated with synthetic chemical manufacture.

Typical compounds in this group that might be responsible for the soot aroma are volatile phenols:

3-methylphenol (tarry/leathery odour)
4-methylphenol (tarry/smoky odour)
2-ethylphenol (smoky odour, phenolic flavour)
2-methoxyphenol (smoky/woody odour)

A special substance that is believed to be responsible for a strong, petrolly kerosene-like aroma developed during aging is 1,1,6-trimethyl-1,2-dihydronaphthalene, which is formed from carotene breakdown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to get those chemicals to smell and taste, preferably not to have to buy every one in a 50g charge? Something like  some university or school for food-chemistry providing access to public one  a year ... or something alike?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Suggest not to taste pure [Cresol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cresol)...